# Rails form_for submit button does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here, but can't for the life of me figure out what.

I have a form where I update attributes of a model.

```
            <%= form_for @gf do |f| %>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :address_line_one, :placeholder => "Address" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :address_line_two, :placeholder => "Address (second line)" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => "City" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :state, :placeholder => "State" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :zip_code, :placeholder => "Zip Code" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.text_field :phone_number, :placeholder => "Phone Number" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
                    </div>
            <%end%>
```

the relevant controller is

```
def home 
    if current_user.girlfriends.all.count == 0
        @gf = Girlfriend.new
        @gf.user_id = current_user.id
    else
        @gf = current_user.girlfriends.first
    end     
end

def new
    raise
end

def create
    raise
end

def update
    raise
end

def delete
    raise
end
```

in my `routes` file

```
resources :girlfriends
```

The form is on the `/home` page, so the `@gf` variable is being properly set. The form fills in the proper fields with the proper attributes. However - when I click `Submit` nothing happens. No change in the URL, no action on the page, I don't hit the `raise` in any of my CRUD actions.... What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: here's the HTML as it's actually rendered.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/girlfriends/1" class="edit_girlfriend" id="edit_girlfriend_1" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="CIPzkLLWwmclyOwKpkphMJ5u8Saxhx6ajDq/NvW8Lfc=" /></div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_first_name" name="girlfriend[first_name]" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="Melissa" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_last_name" name="girlfriend[last_name]" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_address_line_one" name="girlfriend[address_line_one]" placeholder="Address" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_address_line_two" name="girlfriend[address_line_two]" placeholder="Address (second line)" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_city" name="girlfriend[city]" placeholder="City" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_state" name="girlfriend[state]" placeholder="State" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_zip_code" name="girlfriend[zip_code]" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input id="girlfriend_phone_number" name="girlfriend[phone_number]" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you have JavaScript on your page that is keeping the form from submitting.

Comment: I have other forms that do work though... for example I have Devise working with all the sign_up and sign_in forms working fine. Anything else it could be?

Comment: If you look at the page source, is the URL that Rails generated for the form accurate? I have had issues where Rails doesn't add an `action` parameter to a form so it submits to the same page. But you should still see a submit (unless you have turbolinks or something running that's making it not reload the whole page).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. it's generating `<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />` as the HTML. Looks right to me - this is the same as the other forms I have which are working. What do you mean by the missing `action` parameter?

Comment: I think I get what you mean. The `action` in my form is `action="/girlfriends/1"`, when I want this to post to `"/home"`. Think that's the issue? I don't have any views set up beyond `home` for this controller.

Comment: Will you post your routing configurations for your girlfriends controller section ?

Comment: routes are just `resources :girlfriends` and  `get '/home', to: 'girlfriends#home'`

Comment: FWIW I also just edited my post to include how the form is actually being rendered in case it helps. Thanks for any advice you can give me - been stuck for hours!

Comment: Yeah, the form `action` attribute it correct. Are you seeing anything in your server logs that shows that the form POSTs?

Comment: nope - it's literally doing nothing when I click the button. Frustrating!

Comment: @jwadsack 14 hours later, and your first comment was right. Totally missed where this was happening. I had a JQuery file with `event.preventDefault()` being called, which was disabling my button. Happy to upvote you & mark as answer if you post that as an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you have JavaScript on your page that is keeping the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the url is not changing. Create a show.html.erb file in your views and

give a try to this

```
<% form_for :girlfriend, @gf, :url=> {:action => :create},:html => { :method     => :post }do |f| %>
```

And also make new.html.erb for your form contents; and modify your conroller

```
def new
    @gf = Girlfriend.new
end
```

Comment: this gives the error `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)`. Also - wouldn't this limit me to only being able to create a new entry? The goal of using `form-for` here is that the form will choose which action to use based on whether or not the record already exists.

Comment: Remove the `:girlfriend` parameter. But if you share this form between `new` and `edit` you'll need to change the action appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This JS event happens when you are calling jQuery twice on the page. Example: there is the call in the gemfile and another query.js file in assets/javascripts